# Paramiko SSH exec_command (shell script) returns before completion

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I launch a shell script from a remote Linux machine using Paramiko. The shell script is  launched and execute a command `make -j8`. However the `exec_command` returns before the completion of the make.

If I launch the script on the local machine it executes correctly.

Could someone explain me this behaviour?

Answer (score 30):

You need to wait for application to finish, exec_command isn't a blocking call.

```
print now(), "before call"
stdin, stdout, sterr = ssh.exec_command("sleep(10)")
print now(), "after call"
channel = stdout.channel
print now(), "before status"
status = channel.recv_exit_status()
print now(), "after status"
```

Comment: weirdly, using stdout.channel.recv_exit_status() blocks my code forever

Comment: @sliders_alpha Indeed, while this answer is in principle correct, this simple implementation will hang/deadlock, if the command's output is sufficiently large. See [Paramiko ssh die/hang with big output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31625788/850848).