# basic paramiko exec_command help

Tags: python, paramiko

I'm a new paramiko user and am having difficulty running commands on a remote server with paramiko. I want to export a path and also run a program called `tophat` in the background. I can login fine with `paramiko.sshclient()` but my code to `exec_command` has no results.

```
stdin, stdout, sterr = ssh.exec_command('export PATH=$PATH:/proj/genome/programs
/tophat-1.3.0/bin:/proj/genome/programs/cufflinks-1.0.3/bin:/proj/genome/programs/
bowtie-0.12.7:/proj/genome/programs/samtools-0.1.16')

stdin, stdout, sterr = ssh.exec_command('nohup tophat -o /output/path/directory -I 
10000 -p 8 --microexon-search -r 50 /proj/genome/programs/bowtie-0.12.7/indexes
/ce9 /input/path/1 /input/path/2 &')
```

there is no `nohup.out` file and python just goes to the next line with no error messages. I have tried without `nohup` as well and the result is the same. I was trying to follow [this paramiko tutorial](http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/05/ssh-programming-with-paramiko-completely-different/).

am I using `exec_command` incorrectly?

Comment: The second command runs in a different shell from the first one, so the `export` will have no effect.

Comment: You'd do better to just put the environment variable in the one line. That is: `ssh.exec_command('PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:etcetera nohup ...')`; this will export it for the single command only, which is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 14):

I also ran into the same issue and after looking at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215727/paramiko-ssh-exec-commandshell-script-returns-before-completion) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3215773/630364), I see the solution is to call the `recv_exit_status()` method of the Channel. Here is my code:

```
import paramiko
import time

cli = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
cli.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.client.AutoAddPolicy())
cli.connect(hostname="10.66.171.100", username="mapping")
stdin_, stdout_, stderr_ = cli.exec_command("ls -l ~")
# time.sleep(2)    # Previously, I had to sleep for some time.
stdout_.channel.recv_exit_status()
lines = stdout_.readlines()
for line in lines:
    print line

cli.close()
```

Now my code will be blocked until the remote command is finished. This method is explained [here](http://paramiko-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.recv_exit_status), and please pay some attention to the warning.

Comment: this works for me, it could be nice to make the output more pythonic by removing the semicolons at the end of each line.

Comment: @IgnacioTartavull Removed the semicolons. When I wrote the code above, I just turned to Python from C++. :-)

Answer (score 9):

**exec_command()** is non blocking, and it just sends the command to the server then Python will run the following code.

I think you should wait for the command execution ends and do the rest work after that.

"time.sleep(10)" could help which requires "import time".
Some examples show that you could read from the stdout *ChannelFile* object, or simply using **stdout.readlines()**, it seems to read all the response from the server, guess this could help.

Your code, the above 2 lines of **exec_command**, they're actually running in different exec sessions. I'm not sure if this has some impact in your case.

I'd suggest you take a look at [the demos in the demos folder](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/tree/main/demos), they're using [Channel](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/channel.html) class, which has better API to do blocking / nonblocking sending for both shell and exec.

Comment: I had a similar problem and I just wanted to chime in and say that stdout.readlines() worked great for me. It forced my script to wait until the exec_command() was finished running before continuing. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You better to load the bash_profile before you run your command. Otherwise you may get a 'command not found' exception.

For example，I write the command `command = 'mysqldump -uu -pp -h1.1.1.1 -P999 table > table.sql'` in the purpose of dumping a Mysql table

Then I have to load the bash_profile manually before that dumping command by typing `. ~/.profile; .~/.bash_profile;`.

## Example

```
my_command  = 'mysqldump -uu -pp -h1.1.1.1 -P999 table > table.sql;'

pre_command = """
. ~/.profile;
. ~/.bash_profile;
"""

command = pre_command + my_command

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
```

Comment: No, you better run a command which doesn't require anything from your `.profile` or other interactive shell startup files. This is a workaround when you have foolishly defined e.g. an alias in your startup file or need to run a command which is not in your `PATH`; but the fix for the former is to simply not do that (spell out the command in longhand instead of trying to use the alias) and for the latter to pass a full path to the command (e.g. `/usr/lib/sendmail` instead of just `sendmail`).