# How to detect if command executed using Paramiko invoke_shell has finished

Tags: python, tkinter, ssh, paramiko

I'm trying to perform backup using Paramiko. When backup occurs I let script sleep for 240 seconds hoping it is complete however sometimes this may take longer than this. Is there anyway I can use a loop to keep checking every 20 seconds to see if such keywords such as "backup complete" exist is the output variable.

```
import datetime, time
from time import sleep
from Tkinter import *
import paramiko
from paramiko_expect import SSHClientInteraction
def backup():
prompt = 'root@servername user'
try:
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys() 
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()) 

    client.connect(hostname=server, username=user, password=pass)

    interact = SSHClientInteraction(client, timeout=10, display=True)


except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
    print("Authentication failed, please verify your credentials: %s")
except paramiko.SSHException as sshException:
    print("Unable to establish SSH connection: %s" % sshException)
except paramiko.BadHostKeyException as badHostKeyException:
    print("Unable to verify server's host key: %s" % badHostKeyException)
except Exception as e:
    print(e.args)

    interact.send('su')
    interact.expect("Password:")


    interact.send("supassword")
    interact.expect(prompt)


    interact.send("who")
    interact.expect(prompt)

    cmd_output_who = interact.current_output_clean
    print cmd_output_who
```

Answer (score 1):

[`SSHClient.invoke_shell`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.invoke_shell) is for implementing an interactive terminal sessions (like if you are implementing your own SSH terminal client), not for automating a command execution. A terminal is a black box with input and output. It does not have any API to execute a command and wait for it to complete.

Use [`SSHClient.exec_command`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command) to execute the command and [`Channel.recv_exit_status`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.recv_exit_status) or [`Channel.exit_status_ready`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.exit_status_ready) to wait for it to complete.
See [Wait until task is completed on Remote Machine through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28485647/850848).