# Paramiko exec_command, can't make code awaits for task to be completed

Tags: django, docker, ssh, celery, paramiko

I am building a django app under docker. In the views I call a task where paramiko makes a ssh connection from a container to another to run a third party app. The problem is that during the call to the other container I zip the 'results' folder and move it to another place. This requires a bit. The code though goes back to the views and looks for the zip file before it appears where it should be.

**tasks.py**

```
@shared_task()
def my_task():
        command2 = f"""sudo cp /.../ibt1.msh /.../ibt1.msh && \n 

        until sudo zip -r result.zip ./output/; do sleep 5; done && \n


        until sudo mv result.zip /europlexusData/result.zip; do sleep 5; done && \n
        sudo rm -rf ./output
        """

        host2 = "+"
        port = ++
        username = "+"
        password = "+"

        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(host2, port, username, password)
        stdin, stdout, stderror = ssh.exec_command(command2, get_pty=True)
        
        return 'Done'
```

**views.py**

```
    my_task.delay()
    file=open('zip/file/to/be/created/in/the/task')
    return FileResponse(file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `my_task.delay()` means my_task will run in parallel with the rest of your view. This means my_task might not even be started when you call open on the line after. If you remove the call to `delay()` your task will run until its end and open will happen after.

This is not a good practice because your request might timeout and your server will get busy for nothing, instead you should:

1. Warn your client that the task has been started.
2. Once you know it is done (via a messaging service, or waiting sufficiently long enough) have your client query an other route that fetches the resulting zip.

---

As mentioned by Martin Prikryl: That's still only one part of the problem. The other is that my_task does not wait for the remote command to finish. For that, see [Paramiko SSH exec_command (shell script) returns before completion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3215727/850848) – Though for really correct code, see also [Paramiko ssh die/hang with big outpu.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31625788/850848).